# MS Access "#Name?" in unbound field on SOME machines

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, field

I have a datasheet form bound to table. I added 2 unbound fields and set their Control Source properties to user defined VBA functions:
1. ConcatRelated (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)
2. Custom function that returns a string:

```
Public Function GetLowestSatatus(LookupField As String, JSAID As Integer) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLowestSatatus = DLookup(LookupField, "JsaStatuses", "ID=" & DMin("StatusID", "Tasks", "JSAID =" & JSAID))
End Function
```

It works fine on my and some other machines but there are machines I got "#Name?" in these 2 unbound fields. All machines configured identically.

Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Comment: I tried to copy that form but result is the same. Then I created the form AGAIN with all the same settings and properties AND IT WORKS! I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when proper data is not contained in the LookupField or JSAID origin fields. To avoid this problem I use variants as arguments for user defined functions that will be called from a control's controlsource.

```
Public Function GetLowestSatatus(LookupField, JSAID) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLowestSatatus = DLookup(LookupField, "JsaStatuses", "ID=" & DMin("StatusID", "Tasks", "JSAID =" & JSAID))
End Function
```